# UWP BitmapEncoder SetProperties is not supported

Tags: c#, c++, graphics, directx, uwp

So I'm creating a UWP app and need to write text and images to an image file and save them. I've currently created a D2D wrapper in C++ using [this source](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-add-wartermark-f6313fad/view/SourceCode) and then a C# wrapper that simply lets you access the functions of the C++ class in nice C# code (it does nothing else but access the WINMD C++ wrapper).

However, after we write the image and text to the stream, we need to be able to save the file **with EXIF headers** containing info about rotation and location.

We are using `encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync` to accomplish this, but it returns:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Tester.exe

Additional information: The operation is unsupported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F81)
```

There is no inner exception and the stack trace is:

```
   at Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.get_BitmapProperties()
   at Tester.ViewModels.<_SaveImageWithPropertiesAsync>d__56.MoveNext()
```

I want to try to avoid manually adding the headers, as I fear the returned stream from the D2DContext doesn't contain any header information or whatnot so it can't append anything to it.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

### C++

Again, you can find the original source [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-add-wartermark-f6313fad/view/SourceCode)

```
IRandomAccessStream^ D2DWrapper::EndDraw()
{
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        m_d2dContext->EndDraw()
    );

    // If needPreview is true, we return a valid IRandomAccessStream reference.

    GUID wicFormat = GUID_ContainerFormatBmp;
    ComPtr<IStream> stream;
    ComPtr<ISequentialStream> ss;
    auto inMemStream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        CreateStreamOverRandomAccessStream(inMemStream, IID_PPV_ARGS(&stream))
        );

    SaveBitmapToStream(m_targetBitmap, m_wicFactory, m_d2dContext, wicFormat, stream.Get());

    return inMemStream;

}
```

### C# Wrapper

```
public IRandomAccessStream EndDraw() {
    return _context.EndDraw()
}
```

### C# Tester

```
async Task _SaveImageWithPropertiesAsync(UWPImaging.Image image, PhotoOrientation photoOrientation)
{
    var ras = await image.EndDraw();

    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(ras);

    var file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
        "test.jpeg",
        CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(outputStream, decoder);

        var properties = new BitmapPropertySet { { "System.Photo.Orientation", new BitmapTypedValue(photoOrientation, PropertyType.UInt16) } };

        await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties); // This is where the error occurs

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Any help on how to get those headers in would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

#### Nolan

Comment: I'm also getting same issue. Found any solution?

Comment: @Vishnu, I unfortunately have not. I ended up changing our internal code to work around this issue. It's dumb, but basically we are writing to a stream, then reading the stream in c# and writing the file headers there. Apologies for a poor solution

Answer (score 0):

If the target container is different (ex. JPEG to TIFF), then you need to modify metadata before writing them, according to the target container specifications. WIC Explorer can help you understand the metadata structure of files. I found that some codecs (ex. HEIF) freeze the app when trying to get all the available metadata, so better to manually pick what's needed.